# Accessing previous elements of python list comprehension

Tags: list, element

I have the following list:

```
a = [1,(landa/mu)]
```

I want to add elements to this list using previous elements:

```
a = a + [[f(i)*a[n-i] for i in range(1,n)] for n in range(2,K)]
```

in which f is a function and landa, mu and K are parameters. However, it is giving me the following error:

```
list index out of range
```

Could you please tell me how can I solve this problem? I can simply write it in a for loop but I want it to be in a list comprehension format to be done fast since K sometimes become a large number.

Comment: List comprehensions are just a compact way of writing a `for` loop that appends things to a list, so your code won't really get any faster because the underlying algorithm will still be exactly the same. Look at using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) instead, which has support for vectorized operations on arrays.